How to grab Alt key without swallowing it?
I'm implementing Alt-Tab functionality for i3wm. To do so, I'm writing a Python3 program communicating with i3 using the i3ipc package.
I use the Xlib package to grab "Alt-Tab", so my program can change focus accordingly. This works.
In addition, my program needs to update its internal window list when the "Alt" key is released. Therefore I also grab the "Alt" key, and this is where things don't work as expected.
The Problem
Consider the following code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from Xlib import X, XK, display

class KeyInterceptor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.local_display = display.Display()
        self.root_window = self.local_display.screen().root

        self.modifier = "Alt_L"
        self.mod_sym = XK.string_to_keysym(self.modifier)
        self.mod_code = self.local_display.keysym_to_keycode(self.mod_sym)

        # Grab Alt, async
        print(f'Grabbing {self.modifier}, sym={self.mod_sym}, code={self.mod_code}')
        self.root_window.grab_key(
           self.mod_code, 0, 1, X.GrabModeAsync, X.GrabModeAsync)

    def run(self):
        """Event loop. Blocking forever."""
        while True:
            event = self.local_display.next_event()

            keysym = self.local_display.keycode_to_keysym(event.detail, 0)
            key = XK.keysym_to_string(keysym)

            if event.type == X.KeyPress:
                print(f"'{key}' (sym {keysym}) went down")
                if keysym == self.mod_sym:
                    print(f"    Modifer DOWN detected'")
                    # Forward the event
                    self.local_display.allow_events(X.ReplayKeyboard, X.CurrentTime)

            if event.type == X.KeyRelease:
                print(f"'{key}' (sym {keysym}) went up")
                if keysym == self.mod_sym:
                    print(f"    Modifer UP detected")
                    # Forward the event
                    self.local_display.allow_events(X.ReplayKeyboard, X.CurrentTime)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    interceptor = KeyInterceptor()
    interceptor.run()

I have two problems:

Pressing "Alt" is properly detected, but other X11 clients don't see the key press. I expected that allow_events() would forward the key press to other X11 clients.
Releasing the "Alt" key is not detected. Maybe the event queue got stuck somehow?

